# Code can not find Getters and Setters; Not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, getter-setter

I am making authorization for a web application. And I an faced witw problem. I can not use Getters and Setters. Namely setActive ans setRole. And I can not create variable UserFromDb.

RegistrationController.java

```
import com.Vova.Restart.Models.Role;
import com.Vova.Restart.repo.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;


@GetMapping("/registration")
public String registration() {
    return "registration";
}

@PostMapping("/registration")
public String addUser (User user, Map<String, Object> model) {
    userFromDb = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if (userFromDb != null) {
        model.put("message", "User exists!");
        return "registration";
    }

    user.setActive(true);
    user.setRole(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));

    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

}

User.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String username, password;
private boolean active;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "userRole", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<Role> roles;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public void setRole(Set<Object> singleton) {

}
}
```

I tried to use import com.Vova.Restart.Models.User instead import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User and this error has gone but i get another problem `Not a managed type: class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`. I think this is wrong imort. How can i solve it?

Comment: Your need to let Spring Data know about your entity classes. It seems like it’s picking up a spring security user class. Check your imports

Comment: Managed entity i.e. Entity Class is the one annotated with `@Entity`. Since `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` is not an entity, you are getting this error. Change import